# Using saveEventually() instead of save() or saveInBackground() for ParseUser or ParseObject

Tags: parse-platform

Looking at Parse documentation, there is a saveEventually() method that can be used in place of save() and saveInBackground().

Can I use this function everywhere in my code in place of save and saveInBackground so I don't have to worry about the user switching between being offline and online and I won't have to handle saving in situations where there is no connectivity? Are there any drawbacks to using this approach?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to Parse's [iOS guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS):

> Most save functions execute immediately, and inform your app when the save is complete. If you don't need to know when the save has finished, you can use saveEventually instead. The advantage is that if the user currently doesn't have a network connection, saveEventually will store the update on the device until a network connection is re-established. If your app is closed before the connection is back, Parse will try again the next time the app is opened.

So you will use `save` if you need the callback when the save has finished. I think you can use both depending on the situation you are handling.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into my scenarios and use the methods appropriately. I missed that part because I was reading the android documentation I think.

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal please let me know if you are using saveEventually instead of save. I'm thinking to use it in the same way as you.

Comment: @juancho well it depends on your specific use case, but I ended up using saveEventually since I didn't require a callback.

Comment: Thanks @VaibhavAggarwal ! As I understand, it will try to send it first to the cloud and then to the local storage so it's doing what I need.