# Offline caching with Parse.com?

Tags: android, parse-platform, offline-caching

I was trying to make my app based on parse.com available offline, the official tutorial can be found here: blog.parse.com/2014/04/30/take-your-app-offline-with-parse-local-datastore/

In my app, I provide a button to connect to internet, get the list of all ParseObjects I want to keep and pin them all. My app is just a listview that populates from local datastore.

When I tried my app with airplane mode on, I was hoping that it could load from previous objects that have been pinned. But it freezes instead, prompts me to exit the app because it isn't responding. LogCat says "com.parse.parseexception i/o failure" which obviously is an internet connection problem.

I just want to save the cache so users won't have to refresh new data every time the app is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [parse api](http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/).`saveEventually()` would be the function that you want to use or you can use internal storage to save the parse object.It is mentioned detailed [here](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/caching-objects-in-android-internal-storage/).

Comment: isn't saveEventually() for keeping data offline and upload it later when you are online?

Comment: I am still figuring out what exactly does saveEventually() does and also the link you mentioned. I'll be sure to accept the answer if it does helps.

Comment: From the api docs ....Most save functions execute immediately, and inform your app when the save is complete. If you don't need to know when the save has finished, you can use saveEventually instead. The advantage is that if the user currently doesn't have a network connection, saveEventually will store the update on the device until a network connection is re-established. If your app is closed before the connection is back, Parse will try again the next time the app is opened.

Comment: @Anggrian i hope this helps you ..and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583429/using-saveeventually-instead-of-save-or-saveinbackground-for-parseuser-or