# save offline data after Connection, saveEventually() meet i/o failure

Tags: android, parsing, parse-platform

As we know ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327477/offline-caching-with-parse-com)), `saveEventually()` can help develop build application save data temporary, when connection build again, `saveEventually()` will help my data async to Parse Server automatically.

But sometime I meet issues is when async situation, ParseException said i/o failure, hope someone can help, thanks

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("abc");
        saveParseObjectID = getSharedPreferences("saveParseObjectID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        query.getInBackground(saveParseObjectID.getString("cloud","a"), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    object.put("tag", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                    object.saveEventually();
                } else {
                    Log.d("errorTAG:", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

and here is the log

```
08-09 03:01:17.504    2007-2007/? D/errorTAG: i/o failure
```

80% will success, but sometime will have i/o failure issue after build new Internet Connection, I check StackOverflow said I need check my connection,
but the feature I use `saveEventually()` is want to bring offline data to online, please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add this if() to build saveEventually() and Success, hope help who need this one.

```
 else {
                    Log.d(""tag"", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    if(e.getMessage().equals("i/o failure")){
                        object.put("tag", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                        object.saveEventually();
                        Log.d("saveEventually","check");
                    }
      }
```