# Query Pointer in Parse (ios)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am doing a query and I am checking to see if the value in the column "Parent", which is a pointer, is equal to a string, newLogObjectId.  I obviously cannot do this since a pointer and a string are a different value type, (returns nil).  How do I compare a string to a string in a pointer?

```
    //A string, for example, "MCeKMyxRIt"
    let newLogObjectId = objectIdArray[markerIndex]

    let query1 = PFQuery(className: "ComparablePhotos")
    //"Parent" is a pointer referencing an objectId in another class.  "newLogObjectId" is a string  How do I check to see if the String of Parent is equal to newLogObjectId, a string?
    query1.whereKey("Parent", equalTo:newLogObjectId)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers in Parse don't point to a value, they point to a class (a `PFObject`). So it looks like your pointer named `Parent` is pointing to the Parse class `NewLog`. I'm assuming then the string you are wanting to check is a field in the class `NewLog`. Also, to include the pointer in the query, use `query1.includeKey("PointerName")`. Try this:

```
let newLogObjectId = objectIdArray[markerIndex]

let query1 = PFQuery(className: "ComparablePhotos")
query1.includeKey("Parent")
query1.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (error == nil){
        if let comparablePhotos = objects as? [PFObject]{
            for photo in comparablePhotos {
                if let parentPointer:PFObject = photo["Parent"] as? PFObject{
                    if(parentPointer["columnWithString"] as! String == newLogObjectID){
                        // Do something
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        println(error)
    }

})
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but NewLog is throwing an error.  "Use of undeclared type NewLog"

Comment: Thank you.  I have one more error regarding parentPointer.... its "use of unresolved identifier 'parentPointer'"

Comment: Must've deleted the variable declaration on my first edit, my mistake! This should work for you now.

Comment: Thanks Kyle!  unfortunately I am generating another error.  'Could not find an overload for == that accepts the supplied arguments'....  I really appreciate your help so far.

Comment: It might not know right offhand that it is dealing with a `String`. Try `parentPointer["columnWithString"] as! String == newLogObjectId`

Comment: Say I am trying to save the data in my Images column within the if(parentPointer["columnWithString"] as! String == newLogObjectID){ } section.  How do I do this?

Comment: The `Images` column is part of the class `ComparablePhotos`, which you grab at the line `if let comparablePhotos = objects as? [PFObject]`. Then in the next line you grab each individual object inside your class. So once you edit that item, here called `photo`, just do a `photo.save()` before you grab the next `photo`.

Comment: I tried and couldnt figure it out, could you maybe update the code to fit it?  Ill upvote :D

Comment: Updating my code would no longer fit the original question you asked and may confuse users when they come across this in the future. The additional code I gave you was a single command, but if you can't figure it out I suggest reviewing the [Parse Docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-saving-objects) and even [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583429/using-saveeventually-instead-of-save-or-saveinbackground-for-parseuser-or)